Query git "Changes to be committed" for an `--amend` commit
Executing git commit gives an editor which indicates 'Changes to be committed':
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# Date:      Tue Dec 10 12:17:16 2024 -0800
#
# On branch tmp
# Changes to be committed:
#       deleted:    foo
#       deleted:    bar
#       deleted:    baz
#
# Untracked files:
#       qux
#

How can I get this complete list for some automation I'm writing into a git pre-commit hook?
A naive solution might be to run git diff --cached --name-only, but a special case in which that command is insufficient is when the current commit is an --amend: for --amend, git composes the complete list of 'Changes to be committed' from both the staged (cached) changes and whatever was already committed. How can I get this complete list?
Edit
(I know I can get the complete list of files if I know whether the current commit is an --amend. For instance, git commit --dry-run will give it to me. But my automation doesn't have that information available.)

I've deleted my answer for now, but I'll keep thinking to an alternative solution

Thanks, @dani-vta. Sorry my first draft wasn't as focused as it could have been.

@Jellicke I checked the pre-commit doc to see if the hook was invoked by passing git commit's options/arguments, but unfortunately it states "It takes no parameters". I was hoping to tell whether the git commit was supplied with --amend or not, and then compute the list of files. It might be that what you want is not possible.

This question is similar to: How to detect commit --amend by pre-commit hook ?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@anthonysottile thanks a lot for your comment, it was really useful to answer the question. However, although the post shares some similarities with the one you've linked, the first one only asks how to recognize an amend commit in a hook, while this one also needs to know how to get the set of changes for a generic commit (regular or amended). I think this question asks something more than the other; enough to consider them different. But ofc this is just my opinion. I invite others to join the discussion.

Thanks to @anthony-sottile's link, I've been able to see that in order to tell whether a commit is an amend or not, we need to use the prepare-commit-msg hook rather than the pre-commit hook, as the latter is invoked with no parameters according to its documentation. Furthermore, because of my rather limited knowledge of shell scripting, I'm offering a pseudocode solution as a reference based on @kunicmarko20's answer.
To get the complete list of changes of a commit, we first need to tell whether this is an amend commit or not. In the former case, the set of changes corresponds to the list of staged files (git diff --cached --name-only), while in the latter it's the list of staged files plus the differences from the previous commit (git diff --name-only HEAD~ HEAD).
The script could look something along the lines:
#./.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg

IS_AMEND=$(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | grep -e '--amend');

# retrieving the staged differences for both cases
# git diff --cached --name-only

# in the case of an amended commit
if [ -n "$IS_AMEND" ]; then
   # retrieving the differences from the previous commit
   # git diff --name-only HEAD~ HEAD
fi

In the previous script, I've simplified the retrieval of changes from the "previous" commit, assuming that in the case of amending a merge commit, you're interested in the changes from the first parent (the current branch), as in that instance HEAD~ and HEAD^ would point to the same commit. I'll leave to you any further logic, if you're interested in a different parent in case of a merge.

But that sounds like it would require my automation to already know if it was an --amend, no? I think the crux of the matter may lie in knowing if the commit underway is an --amend.

That's very true

As said above, my answer only offers a pseudocode solution. If anyone wants to contribute to the script's code, feel free to leave a comment or edit.
